# For new Contributions entered manually, how do I add an "InMemoriam" section to the manual data entry form?

Tags: civicontribute

We occasionally receive donation cheques in memory of someone.  For the public Contribution Page I've created a profile which asks for the particulars (name, rank, other info)of the deceased but I can't figure out how to display that profile when our volunteers are entering information **manually**.
CiviCRM 5.35.0. on WordPress 5.7.1 | PHP 7.3.27 | Apache | MySQL 5.7.23-23

Comment: Are "rank" etc just fields on the contact record? Can you just edit the contact record?

Comment: Are you looking to create a new contact for the deceased, most of the time? I think the workflow could look like: 1) use profile in create mode then 2) record contribution with soft credit to recently created contact. If the deceased contacts already exist, then it would make more sense to search first and then use the profile if needed. It depends on your dedupe rule and tolerance for duplicates.

Comment: No - not looking to create new contacts. And not necessary to check if Deceased is a Contact - it's merely a way for donors to provide info on the person they want to be remembered. We publish the names of the donors and deceased individuals in our newsletter.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly... Profiles that are assigned to Contributions display on the New Contribution input page but they are collapsed by default. We have a custom Profile "Other Details". My first screenshot shows it collapsed and the second one shows it opened.

If you do not see it there, then go into your Profile setting and make sure it is assigned to Contributions.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still stumped. The InMemoriam Profile that I created appears (as intended) on the on-line Contribution page but I also want it  to appear on the off-line New Contribution page. I don't see any way in the Profile Settings to assign that profile to contributions.

Comment: I got it to work. The profile was associated with Donations but the drop down box doesn't appear in the New Contribution page until the user specifies the Contribution Type as Donation.  Thank you for your guidance.